# Moving item from one list to another

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a custom list on the top level site of my collection and also on many sub sites.  Occasionally, I will want to move an item from the list at the top level to a list in the sub sites.  How can I do this using only Sharepoint itself?

- I don't have access to use Designer or STSADM.
- I don't need to do it in bulk, one at a time is ok.
- I want to maintain the meta data like Created By, Modified By, etc

Everything I found on Google was using Designer or STSADM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

It's trivial to do in the Manage Site Content and Structure page but I didn't have it in my Site Actions menu.  I was able to get to it though by putting _layouts/sitemanager.aspx at the end of my URL.

Answer (score -1):

Through API ucan read items from list and these items to another list.